# MySQL and FOREIGN KEY. Disallow NULL on allowed NULL value column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Example of tables

```
t1:

__________
|id | val|
|---+----|
| 1 | a  |
|---+----|
| 2 | b  |
|---+----|
| 3 | c  |
|---+----|


t2:
__________
|id | val|
|---+----|
| 1 | d  |
|---+----|
| 2 | e  |
|---+----|
| 3 | f  |
|---+----|
T:
    ________________________________
    |id | val| fk_t1_id | fk_t2_id |
    |---+----|----------+----------|
    | 1 | g  |    1     |   NULL   |
    |---+----|----------+----------|
    | 2 | h  |    NUL   |    1     |
    |---+----|----------+----------|
    | 3 | i  |    3     |   NULL   |
    |---+----|----------+----------|
```

Both 'fk_t1_id' and 'fk_t2_id' are foreign keys fileds and both are NULL allowed.
Is it possible to make additional constraint which will allows only 1 FK on one field and NULL on another? (to be impossible insert row where both 'fk_t1_id' and 'fk_t2_id' are NULL or both of it are NOT NULL)

Comment: In MySQL, you can only do this with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Create a check constraint on the T table having condition:
CHECK( (fk_t1_id is not NULL and fk_t2_id is NULL) OR (fk_t1_id is NULL and fk_t2_id is NOT NULL))

Comment: MySQL does not enforce check constraints, so this will actually do nothing.

Comment: What do you mean? I hope I am not missing something here but you can use a check constraint ...  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: @GordonLinoff, agree with you, TRIGGER is a solution. Thanks, post your answer and I'll check it as "ANSWER" to close this question.

Comment: @EduardUta, this method only check if inserted - so it allow to insert, but I need constraint on insert!

Comment: @EduardUta . . . "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.4, “Foreign Keys”." (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for sharing the above with me.